# LibGdx: How do I combine 2 GestureListener objects from 2 seperate classes into 1 GestureDetector

Tags: java, libgdx, input

I'm trying to make 2 separate classes, 1 a VirtualJoystick class and 1 a VirtualButton class. I want to implement a GestureListener class in each, it just seems like good code to do so, but when I go to my main program, how do I add both GestureListener classes?

Here's some pseudocode that I'm thinking of:

```
VirtualJoystick vjs = new VirtualJoystick(x, y, width, height, bgImage, fgImage);
VirtualButton vb    = new VirtualButton(x,  y,  width, height, upImage, dnImage);

GestureDetector joyGestureDetector = new GestureDetector( vjs.getDetector() );
GestureDetector btnGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(  vb.getDetector() );

// Here's what I don't know how to do
GestureDetector combinedGestureDetector = ?

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(combinedGestureDetector);
```

but as you can see, I'm stuck on how to combine the two, if there's a better way let me know, I'm just trying to get my code to "think through well" and be atomically contained in classes.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm going about this all wrong, I know now that I can use Gdx.input.isTouched(); but I'm not sure how to do multiple buttons and a joystick just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to fix this is to use [InputMultiplexer](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html). This allows you to pass those gesture events to both detectors.

```
VirtualJoystick vjs = new VirtualJoystick(x, y, width, height, bgImage, fgImage);
VirtualButton vb    = new VirtualButton(x,  y,  width, height, upImage, dnImage);

GestureDetector joyGestureDetector = new GestureDetector( vjs.getDetector() );
GestureDetector btnGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(  vb.getDetector() );
//Note: you need return false in your event handlers like touchDown(...), 
//so that the event gets passed to both detectors you added to the multiplexer.
InputMultiplexer multiplexer= new InputMultiplexer(joyGestureDetector,btnGestureDetector);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```